# Trust SSL Certificate in window container

Tags: docker, containers, ssl-certificate, window

I am getting following error while run docker container:

```
Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
```

I am using `window container`

TO resolve this issue, I added below commands in the docker file:

```
COPY HelloWorld.cer ./certs/

RUN powershell Import-Certificate -FilePath C:\certs\HelloWorld.cer -CertStoreLocation Cert:\localmachine\My
```

After added above commands in docker file, docker image created successfully, but container not running and getting same error.

It seems certificate added in the container but unable to trust the certificate.
What is the way to trust the `SSL certificate` for `window container` ?